# Deserializing json in unity returns nothing

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I'm using Jsonutility, the json file is read correctly but when checking the values of the class I get 0. I looked around similar questions but the result is the same, I either get 0 or null whenever I check the values after Deserializing. I think the problem is with how the json is formatted.

here's my json :

```
    {
   "StatsValues":{
      "HealthStat":{
         "_Min":700,
         "_Max":1200,
         "_Color":"255,255,255",
         "_Opacity":0.1
      },
      "SickStat":[
         {
            "name":"Sickness 1 name",
            "_Min":700,
            "_Max":1200,
            "_Color":"255,255,255",
            "_Opacity":0.1
         },
         {
            "name":"Sickness 2 name",
            "_Min":700,
            "_Max":1200,
            "_Color":"255,255,255",
            "_Opacity":0.1
         },
         {
            "name":"Sickness 3 name",
            "_Min":700,
            "_Max":1200,
            "_Color":"255,255,255",
            "_Opacity":0.1
         },
         {
            "name":"Sickness 4 name",
            "_Min":700,
            "_Max":1200,
            "_Color":"255,255,255",
            "_Opacity":0.1
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and My code :

```
StatsValues _stats = JsonUtility.FromJson<StatsValues>(jsonFile);


    [System.Serializable]
public class StatsValues
{
    public HealthStat _healthStats;
    public List<SickStat> _sickStats;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class HealthStat
{
    public int _Min;
    public int _Max;
    public string _Color;
    public float _Opacity;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class SickStat
{
    public string name;
    public int _Min;
    public int _Max;
    public string _Color;
    public float _Opacity;
}
```

Comment: try to match the variable names in the json with the c# class and tell me if it works

Comment: already matched as u can see in the json & the classes code

Comment: @derHugo that's what I'm trying to say, match "variables" names, cause _sickStats variable is not the same as SickStats object variable in the json

Comment: Yes thank you, I was confused for a bit and I thought that u meant the names OF the classes must match not variables, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have one more nest level in your JSON since the `"StatsValues"` object is wrapped within additional `{ }` so there is one more type object around it
2. Your classes' **field** names have to match exactly the field names in JSON. (The class names do not matter.)

   You have `"HealthStat" : ...` and `"SickStat" : ...`

so it should be:

```
Data _stats = JsonUtility.FromJson<Data>(jsonFile);
var _healthStat = _stats.StatsValues.HealthStat;

[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public StatsValues StatsValues;
}

[Serializable]
public class StatsValues
{
    public HealthStat HealthStat;
    public List<SickStat> SickStat;
}
```

and in order to be a bit more c# like you could also do

```
[Serializable]
public class StatsValues
{
    public Stat HealthStat;
    public List<SickStat> SickStat;
}

[Serializable]
public class Stat
{
    public int _Min;
    public int _Max;
    public string _Color;
    public float _Opacity;
}

[Serializable]
public class SickStat : Stat
{
    public string name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! as I was saying in the reply to @lotan I was confused for a bit and I thought the classes names are the ones to match to the json variables not the names of the fields in the class. thank you for your time!